# How can i check if the result is fraction

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can i check if the result of division of two numbers is fraction in visual basic

here is what i need to do :

```
    Dim x As Integer = 12
    Dim y As Integer = 5

    If TypeOf x/y Is fraction Then
        ( do something )
    End If
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Technically, Integer division will always result in an Integer.  It will never be a fraction.  I assume what you are really looking for, and the answers are suggesting, is how to identify whether or not y is a factor of x.

Comment: @cadrell0 The `/` operator returns the full quotient, including remainder. It's the `\` operator which only returns the integer component. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76(v=vs.80).aspx for citation :)

Comment: Even the question is understandable, the terminology is a bit misleading. Because any number can be written as `a/b` that is in a fraction form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Mod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which will return the remainder of a division.

```
Dim x As Integer = 12
Dim y As Integer = 5

If x Mod y > 0 Then
    MsgBox (x & " / " & y & " has a remainder, so it must be a fraction.")
End If
```

Comment: The link is dead.  Here is a link to MOD on Microsoft's API Reference website. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator

Answer (score 5):

Could you not do the modulus of two numbers and then if that is non zero, it is a fraction?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Mod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) operator to see if x cleanly divides into y:

```
If x Mod y > 0 Then
  ' There will be a fraction. do something
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If x Mod y = 0 ' Not a fraction
If x Mod y <> 0 ' Fraction
```

Comment: @MattWilko It's been way too long. Thanks Matt. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "Mod" operator and check if you can convert it to Integer...

Mod Operator (Visual Basic):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "Fraction" that you mean "non-integer," since technicall any number can be represented as a fraction...

One typical way is to use the modulus operator:

```
If  x MOD y <> 0 Then
  ' x/y is a fraction
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework has `Math.DivRem` so if you'd really prefer to determine the dividend and the remainder at the same time:

```
Dim x As Integer = 12
Dim y As Integer = 5
Dim r As Integer
Dim d As Integer = Math.DivRem(x, y, r)

If r <> 0 Then
    ( do something )
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is much better, O(1) constant

```
If x Mod 1 = 0 Then ' Integer
If x Mod 1 <> 0 Then ' Float
```